# Firebase Console View Bundle detail values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm aware of Google Analytics for capturing the stats etc in android app.

Recently migrated to firbease Console and setup couple of Bundle Id's as mention in Firebase Document https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events problem is I don't see rest of bundle Id only see primary ID.

Can you please guide where to see rest of values in firebase console ( values i'm looking for are QuizName, Questions, CorrectAnswers, CorrectAnsRatio)

I can see these data correctly send in logcat but don't see QuizName, Questions in firebase console. Only see UserData value. 
Am i missing anything?

```
//Log analytics result into bundle
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Player player = PreferencesHelper.getPlayer(getActivity());
        bundle.putString("QuizName",mCategory.getName());
        bundle.putString("Questions",Integer.toString(iCount));
        bundle.putInt("CorrectAnswers",iSolve);
        bundle.putFloat("CorrectAnsRatio",(float)(iSolve *100.0)/iCount);
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("UserData",bundle);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't view that raw data directly in Firebase Analytics Console. But you can use those to create audiences. I didn't remember but this was also said in one of the Firebase Dev Summit analytics event(may be in [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxAOjwSc9sY)).

However, you can export it to the BigQuery (only in BLAZE plan) and then there you can query the data however you want. There was also a talk about this in recent firebase dev summit. (https://youtu.be/zssCC6rXyGk?t=18m21s)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can see comment in Google analytics document now. Not showing custom values in analytics console is not helpful as this was basic feature provided on google analytics?

Comment: don't know how we missed it but thanks again for pointing it out!

Comment: Actually they are more like a meta data of an event. So what you were getting in GA was event categories,action,label and value. They are also available in firebase. Like for category you can prefix your event like for button clicks, `btn_new_event` etc. You can set value (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param.html#VALUE) which is visible in the dashboard. I am also figuring out all the possibilities